# How to filter on basis of JodaTime in objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datetime, objectify

I am new to Google Appengine. In my application, the datastore entities store a org.joda.time.DateTime object. I want to query the datastore to return all the entities in between a range of 2 particular DateTime. My code for this is :

```
@Entity
@Cache
@Index
public class Sample {

    @Id
    Long id; // autogen

    private DateTime dateTime;
    private int activeCount;
    private int inactiveCount;
}
```

I want a query similar to -

```
 Iterable<Sample> sampleIterable = ofy().load().type(Sample.class)
                    .filter("dateTime <", DateTime.now())
                    .filter("dateTime >", DateTime.now().minusDays(1))
                    .iterable();
```

Is it possible to query the DateTime like this ? What would be the correct way to query DateTime in objectify ? I am sorry for the lack of clearity.

Comment: Have you registered the joda date time translators with your objectify service/factory? If so, this should just work, assuming the correct indexes exist (in this case the 'dateTime' field is marked with @Index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you register the Joda translators with Objectify, you can use `DateTime` as both a field and a filter clause. You can use `DateTime` to filter against regular `Date` properties too.

```
JodaTimeTranslators.add(ObjectifyService.factory());
```

This is not enabled by default because everyone would then need to include joda time as a dependency.